# How to Autofit Width Column of CSV File in TEXT_IO Procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have code in which select data from tables and enter data into "CSV" File. Code run successfully but when Open "CSV" File then by default did not Autofit width column. I need when open "CSV" File then Autofil Width columns

**CODE:**

```
PROCEDURE DATA_CSV IS

 BEGIN

 Declare

 LC$Line Varchar2(30000);
 TFile                  TEXT_IO.FILE_TYPE;

 Begin

 TFile := TEXT_IO.FOpen( 'E:\Report_MOF.csv', 'W' );
 text_io.Put_Line(TFile,'HOFID,MOFID,MOFNAME,RID,CNICNO');
 For C1 in 
 ( SELECT b.hofid, b.mofid, b.mofname, b.rid, b.cnicno
         FROM hof a, mof b
        WHERE a.cnicno IN (SELECT cnic_no FROM we_group_hof_k)
        AND a.cnicno = b.cnicno
 )
 Loop
 LC$Line := C1.hofid|| ',' ||C1.mofid|| ',' ||C1.mofname|| ',' ||C1.rid|| ',' ||C1.cnicno;
 TEXT_IO.PUT_LINE( TFile, LC$Line ) ;
 End loop;

 TEXT_IO.FClose( TFile);

 End;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file is merely a text file that contains values separated by commas (thus the name, Comma Separated Values). It does not specify anything about how the data should be displayed.

When you open a CSV file in a spreadsheet program (such as Microsoft Excel), that program reads the data from the text file and decides how it will display it to you, including how wide to make each column.

If you want to change how Excel decides how wide to make each column, you will probably need to give Microsoft a phone call.

Alternatively, use a different software program to display the contents of the CSV file, or write your own :)